# react-native and firebase native: Could not find method plugins

Tags: firebase, gradle

I am trying to configure a project that uses react-native and google firebase native.

The set up for react-native worked fine, but I ran into a problem with google firebase native.
I followed the instructions at [rnfirebase.io](https://rnfirebase.io/).

When I try to sync My project with gradle files from Android Studio, I get the following error:

```
Build file 'C:\github\flashcards\flashcards\android\app\build.gradle' line: 139

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method plugins() for arguments [build_2psolmxgn6smlx7165ef739cv$_run_closure1$_closure5@1b639892] on extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

...
```

Here is the relevant portion of my `/android/build.gradle` file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ...
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14')
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

I added the following two lines to the top of  my `/android/app/build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any suggesions for how to fix this problem?

I expected the `Sync Project with Gradle files` command to complete successfully, but I receive the error described above.